# Flickr Search and Interestingness API are returning incorrect number of results

Tags: flickr

I am calling into [flickr.interestingness.getList](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.interestingness.getList.html) and trying to get 100 photos per page but am noticing that the API inconsistently returns the specified number of photos I'm asking for. It occurs if I sign the call or not.

I had the same experience with [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) when I was sorting by `interestingness-desc`. So I decided to try using flickr.interestingness.getList instead as I thought it had to do with the # of photos returned (I read that the search API acted wonky when more than 4000 photos were returned).

I am able to reproduce this with the [API explorer](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.interestingness.getList). Try it for yourself with these values:

```
Date= 2008-09-22 (I randomly chose that date)
per_page= 100
page= 1
```

The results through the API and API explorer just gave me 84 results. On subsequent calls it returned 74, 78 and even 39 results a few times!

You can even retry the above test with setting `per_page=10` instead to make it easier to count. You'll see that it rarely, if ever returns 10 results.

The response indicates there are "500" total photos, and 5 pages of photos which makes sense since I'm asking for 100 photos per page. Even worse, it says that there should be 100 photos on the page:

```
<photos page="1" pages="5" perpage="100" total="500">
```

What the heck is going on?

Comment: did you ever work this out? having the same issues with a different search endpoint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751581/invalid-flickr-api-response

Comment: I just experimented with some more recent dates and it seems to return the correct number of results every time. So it appears to be limited to just older dates. Everything back to 2011-01-20 (or so) seems to return the correct number. Anything before that returns slightly less...

Comment: @BrettDeWoody: Thanks for confirming the issue.  Since posting the question, I've found scattered reports of this problem all over the web, but no solutions. The oldest occurrence of the issue dates back to 2008 that I've found (but I can't recall the URL).

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. Couple of the threads I'm trying to get updates/info from: 
*    https://secure.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157633155293068/ 
*    https://secure.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157631512108069/